# Has anyone ever compared results from R geepack, Python statsmodels, and SPSS Generalized Estimating Equations?

Tags: python, r, statistics, spss, libgee

I ran my dataset through these 3 platforms and got wildly different results (i.e. very different p-values) although the calculated means and SDs were the same.

This hints that it should not be due to missing data.

Comment: Maybe you are just comparing dofferent models/objects/hypotheses? Statsmodels should replicate R's values

Comment: check defaults,  check that you have "nice" data so that don't run into corner or ill-conditioned cases. statsmodels unit tests compare with R `gee` package and some parts against Stata.

Comment: However, if parameter estimates and standard errors agree, then p-values cannot differ "wildly" (in absolute terms close to zero)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.